# How do I get env variables to load on terminal startup?

Tags: macos, bash

It should be noted that I am on MacOS 12.0.1 and I'm looking to add some **persistent** environment variables.

I have seen posts about creating and adding to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` but I'm not sure which is which. That being said, anything I add there only works after I use `. ./bash_profile` or `source ./bash_profile` once the terminal loads. I have also tried adding `source ./bash_profile` to either bashrc or bash_profile but that gives me a open too many files error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check [this](https://superuser.com/questions/49289/what-is-the-bashrc-file) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the areas where Linux and macOS differ so a lot of articles you find only partially apply to macOS. Mainly, on macOS, each Terminal tab runs a login shell.

- For login shells, `bash` reads `~/.bash_profile` or (if this is missing) `~/.profile`.
- For interactive shells, `bash` reads `~/.bashrc`.

So on macOS it doesn't actually matter which of `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` you choose. It helps to be consistent though and stick to one or the other.

To make environment variables available in all future session, just add them to the file of your choosing:

```
MYVAR='Hello, world'; export MYVAR
```

PS: Personally I have `test -f ~/.bashrc && . ~/.bashrc` in `.profile` and all definitions in `~/.bashrc`. This covers both worlds (at the cost of always loading some stuff which only is applicable to Linux or macOS) and IMHO is good enough for personal use.

Comment: Apple doesn't change how/when `bash` reads its startup files.  The INVOCATION section of the man page exists for a reason.

Comment: "This is one of the areas where Linux and macOS differ"... but they don't.  The **shell** works the same on both.  I know what you meant and you know what you meant but I doubt the OP does.

Comment: So in order to test this theory I added a simple echo command inside of each of the profile, bash_profile, bashrc and none of them run when I start, perhaps I'm placing the files incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

From Apple developer documentation archives [Login Scripts](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/OpenSource/Conceptual/ShellScripting/BeforeYouBegin/BeforeYouBegin.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004268-CH1-SW15):

OS X provides support for login scripts and environment property lists to allow you to set environment variables and aliases that are automatically set whenever you run a new shell. There are two ways to do this:

**Bourne shell (bash, zsh, and so on):**

To persistently set environment variables and add aliases, you can add the appropriate alias, variable assignment, and export commands to the following files:

- *~/.profile*—executed automatically for all login shells.
- *~/.bash_profile*—similar to .profile, but only runs for bash login shells.
- *~/.bashrc* and *~/.zshrc*—executed automatically for all non-login bash or zsh shells (when you explicitly type bash or zsh on the command line or run a script that starts with *#!/bin/bash* or *#!/bin/zsh*).

You may also find it useful to create a .bashrc file that sources your .profile file. For example:

```
. $HOME/.profile
```

Comment: bashrc is only read for interactive shells.